# XPath for elements with descendants?

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

Trying to find an XPath to extract all `Option` nodes with values along with descendants such as `//Option/VolatilityAndVarianceResults`.  This `//*` does not work...

The first node is shown below:

```
<ns0:Std xmlns:ns0="http://something.Out" CutOff="" DataSource="MD" SpotDataSource="MBA_PM">
<Option ValuationDate="01/06/2021" StrategyName="(volatility swap)" DealID="1083448" Instrument="vol swap" ExpiryDate="09/30/2021" DeliveryDate="10/04/2021" Strike="7.85000000" BuySell="Buy" BaseCurrency="USD" TermCurrency="JPY" NotionalCurrency="USD" TriggerDirection2="" BaseCurrency2="" TermCurrency2="" FirstFixingDate="09/30/2020" FixingSourceName="WM" VegaNotional="61000.00000000">
<MarketRates Spot="103.03" ATMVol="6.759" VolSpread="0.2" DepoBase="0.205" DepoTerm="-0.228" ForwardPoints="-0.333" ForwardRate="102.6968" TwentyFiveDeltaRiskReversal="-1.317" TwentyFiveDeltaButterfly="0.32"/>
<MarketVolatility>
<Percent/>
</MarketVolatility>
<BaseCurrency>
<Amount MarketPriceMid="-71140" MarketPriceBid="-79020" MarketPriceAsk="-63260" Delta="" Vega="45044" Gamma="" Rho="" Theta="" MarketVega="44950"/>
<Percent MarketPriceMid="-116.62" MarketPriceBid="-129.54" MarketPriceAsk="-103.71" Delta="" Vega="73.843" Gamma="" Rho="" Theta=""/>
</BaseCurrency>
<TermCurrency>
<Amount MarketPriceMid="-7329590" MarketPriceBid="-8141464" MarketPriceAsk="-6517715" Delta="" Vega="4640920" Gamma="" Rho="" Theta="" MarketVega="4631246"/>
<Percent MarketPriceMid="-12016" MarketPriceBid="-13347" MarketPriceAsk="-10685" Delta="" Vega="7608.1" Gamma="" Rho="" Theta=""/>
</TermCurrency>
<AdditionalCurrency Currency="EUR">
<Amount MarketPriceMid="-57723" MarketPriceBid="-64117" MarketPriceAsk="-51329" Gamma="" Vega="" Theta="" Rho=""/>
<Percent/>
</AdditionalCurrency>
<ResultsinPayoutCurrency>
<Amount/>
<Percent/>
</ResultsinPayoutCurrency>
<ResultsinBase2>
<Amount Delta="" Vega="" Gamma="" Rho="" Theta=""/>
</ResultsinBase2>
<ResultsinTerm2>
<Amount Delta="" Vega="" Gamma="" Rho="" Theta=""/>
</ResultsinTerm2>
<SensitivityMeasures/>
<VolatilityAndVarianceResults WeightedVolatilityBid="6.5526" WeightedVolatilityAsk="6.8114" AccruedVolatility="6.5373" ForwardVolatilityBid="6.5587" ForwardVolatilityAsk="6.9074"/>
<Status Status="Succeed"/>
</Option>
```

to clarify I'm using `DOM Miscrosoft` object to populate an array in `vba`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim pth As String, strXp As String, arrT, c1
    
    pth = Range("pathSDFX").Value2
    c1 = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getfile(pth).path

    strXp = "//Option/[*]"
    arrT = XML2Arr(pth, strXp)
    Arr2Rng arrT, "Sheet1", , , True
End Sub
```

which is applied here:

```
   Function XML2Arr(strPath As String, strXPath As String)
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long, jj As Long, jjNew As Long, iHeader As Long
        Dim fileName As String, arr
        Dim XDoc As Object, nodesList As Object, node As Object
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''        ' writes XML to DOM object
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        
        If Dir(strPath) = "" Then
            MsgBox "Appears there is no xml stored at " & vbCrLf _
            & strPath & "  Exiting..."
            End
        ElseIf InStrRev(strPath, "*.") > 0 Then        'new full strPath (no wild cards)
                strPath = Left(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\")) & Dir(strPath)
        End If
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            fileName = .getFileName(strPath)
        End With
            
        Application.StatusBar = "Getting XML from " & Chr(34) & fileName & Chr(34) & " ..."
        Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        'XDoc.async = False  'Appears not to work on read-only XML
        XDoc.validateOnParse = False
        XDoc.Load (strPath)
        
        
        XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        'XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces
        
        Set nodesList = XDoc.SelectNodes(strXPath)
         If nodesList.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Appears empty or different formated " & fileName & ". Exiting...")
            Exit Function
        End If
        ' 1. get array sizes
        ii = nodesList.Length
        jj = nodesList(0).ChildNodes.Length 'initial # columns
        For i = 1 To ii
            jjNew = nodesList(i - 1).ChildNodes.Length
            If jjNew > jj Then  'if first row has blanks, reset # col to max
                jj = jjNew
                iHeader = i - 1
            End If
        Next
        ReDim arr(1 To ii + 1, 1 To jj) 'size array
        
        ' 2. populate headers
        For j = 0 To jj - 1
            arr(1, j + 1) = nodesList(iHeader).ChildNodes(j).BaseName
        Next
        
        For i = 1 To ii
            For j = 0 To jj - 1
                If Not (nodesList(i - 1).ChildNodes(j) Is Nothing) Then
                    arr(i + 1, j + 1) = nodesList(i - 1).ChildNodes(j).Text
                End If
            Next
        Next
        
        XML2Arr = arr
        'Arr2Rng arr, "Sheet2", , , True
    End Function
```

Comment: If you'd clearly state what you wish to select from the XML, you may be able achieve your goal via XPath with minimal supporting VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to find xpath string expressions to extract all `Option` nodes with values along with descendants such as `//Option/VolatilityAndVarianceResults`. This `//*` does not work...

- `//*` selects all elements in the document.
- `//Option/VolatilityAndVarianceResults` selects all `VolatilityAndVarianceResults` elements that are children of `Option` elements, anywhere in the document.

To select all `Option` elements with at least one `VolatilityAndVarianceResults` child element, use:

```
//Option[VolatilityAndVarianceResults]
```

To select all `Option` elements with at least one child element, use:

```
//Option[*]
```

To select all `Option` elements with at least one `VolatilityAndVarianceResults` descendent element, use:

```
//Option[.//VolatilityAndVarianceResults]
```

Comment: apologies,  I added more details to the OP as first two variants you suggested either result in error `Node test expected here //Option/-->[<--*] `.  the last one might be due to the way the array gets filled i'm checking now.

Comment: Your added code includes `//Option/[*]`, which is syntactically invalid.  Did you mean `//Option[*]`?